# Aruba: Command "seedly-calculator" not found in PATH-variable

Tags: ruby, rspec, aruba

So, I am trying to run the test but I am getting an error says.

`Aruba::LaunchError:Command "seedly-calculator.rb" not found in PATH-variable`

```
-seedly-calculator
 -bin
 -src
 -seedly-calculator.rb
```

I have tried to change the path in rake file but it doesn't work.
My `seedly-calculator.rb` file is in the root directory.

```
require "rspec/core/rake_task"

namespace :spec do
  desc "Run the functional suite against the CLI"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:functional, [] => [:set_path])

  task :set_path do
    project_bin_dir = File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), '..', 'bin')
    ENV['PATH'] = project_bin_dir + ':'+ ENV['PATH']
  end
end
```

it shows error like:

```
  Failure/Error: let(:command) { run "seedly-calculator.rb" }

  Aruba::LaunchError:
  Command "seedly-calculator.rb" not found in PATH-variable "/Users/bilaltariq/Desktop/seedly-calculator/functional_spec/bin:/Users/bilaltariq/Desktop/seedly-calculator/functional_spec/exe:/Users/bilaltariq/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/Users/bilaltariq/Desktop/seedly-calculator/functional_spec/../bin:/Users/bilaltariq/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec:/Users/bilaltariq/.rbenv/shims:/Users/bilaltariq/.asdf/shims:/Users/bilaltariq/.asdf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/bilaltariq/.bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin".
```

I expect it to hit the file so i can write some test.
am i doing something wrong?

[image]

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Command Validation', type: :aruba do
let(:command) { run "seedly-calculator.rb" }

it "wrong/missing arguments" do
  command.write("lookup\n")
  stop_all_commands
  expect(command.output).to end_with("Missing bank_name argument.\n")
end
```

end

```
seedly-calculator.rb:
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Complete bin/setup so that after it is
# run, ruby seedly-calculator.rb can be used to launch
# it.

# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative './src/runner'

if !ARGV.length.zero?
  input = ARGV
  Runner.new.send('process_input', input)
else
  puts "Arguments required!."
end
```

Comment: Can you post what's in `seedly-calculator.rb` ?

Comment: added my seedly-calculator.rb

Answer (score 0):

Update

To run a ruby script using `run` you need to make sure your ruby script is executable and contains a shebang so your system knows to run it with ruby.  Here's example from [this starter example](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba-getting-started)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file = ARGV[0]

if file.nil? || file.empty?
  abort "aruba-test-cli [file]: Filename is missing"
elsif !File.exist? file
  abort "aruba-test-cli [file]: File does not exist"
end

puts File.read(file).chomp
```

So in your case you'll need to add this to the first line of your `seedly-calculator.rb` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then run this from command line to make it executable.

```
chmod +x #!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

I made a simple example forked off the one I reffed above.  [See this commit](https://github.com/lacostenycoder/simple-aruby-specs/commit/0a9de68262cfb5425f0c9c7b4990cf07e302e871)

Rspec convention is that it should match the same file structure of your project.  It is not a good idea to set PATH manually.

Rake tasks are normally put in a tasks folder so you should have in project root a tasks folder

```
my_project/tasks/something.rake
```

Then you should have a spec folder that matches

```
my_project/spec/tasks/something_spec.rb
```

Then you should be able to get rid of  `task :set_path do end`  block and just run the spec without that.

You should also have a Gemfile to load your gems, run `bundle install` then invoke your test with

```
bundle exec rspec spec/tasks/sometask_spec.rb
```

Comment: so do i still need these
`project_bin_dir =File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'seedly-calculator.rb')`
 `ENV['PATH'] = project_bin_dir + ':'+ ENV['PATH']`

Comment: @NickBb nah you can probably remove all that junk

Comment: @locostenycoder so i removed it from there and added bundle exec rspec in my execution but i am still getting the same aruba error `Aruba::LaunchError:
       Command "seedly-calculator.rb" not found in PATH-variable`

Comment: @locostenycoder very confused. I have all the functionalities working. 
and rspec is working when my file is inside the bin folder. 
but i want it outside and everytime i add it outside it shows me error that cant find such file.

Comment: ie there anyway i can personaly message you!

Comment: my all files are executable.